# Duplicate rows when using orderby, Skip() and Take() with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, c#-3.0

I'm using the following code to query my database:

```
private const int PAGE_SIZE = 10;

public static IList<Image> GetTopImagesForUser(String connectionString, int userID, int page)
{
    dbDataContext db = new dbDataContext(connectionString);
    var images = (from p in db.Images
                  where (p.SubmitterUserIndex == userID &&
                         p.URL != "none" &&
                         p.ThumbURL != "none")
                  orderby p.Rep descending
                  select p).Skip(page * PAGE_SIZE).Take(PAGE_SIZE);
    /* snip */
    return topImages;
}
```

If I call this code with a **page** of 0, everything works the way I want it to - I get a nicely ordered list, 10 results, everything is correct.

If I call this code with a **page** of 1, however, rows that were in page 0 end up in page 1. I can't even begin to understand why. I've checked my database for duplicate rows, none. I've checked to make sure every row's **URL** and **ThumbURL** are not "none". That's not the problem either. I've checked to make sure **page** is what I expect it to be when I call this method, and it is always what I expect it to be.

What really baffles me is that the following method, which differs from the first method only in the **orderby** clause, *works completely as expected*.

```
public static IList<Image> GetAllImagesForUser(String connectionString, int userID, int page)
{
    dbDataContext db = new dbDataContext(connectionString);
    var images = (from p in db.Images
                  where (p.SubmitterUserIndex == userID &&
                         p.URL != "none" &&
                         p.ThumbURL != "none")
                  orderby p.SubmitTime descending
                  select p).Skip(page * PAGE_SIZE).Take(PAGE_SIZE);
    /* snip */
    return allImages;
}
```

Has anyone run into something like this? Is there a different form that my query should take to do what I want it to do? I'm not sure what I could be missing.

Comment: This is such a good question. When you first encounter this problem, it is just mind-boggling.

Comment: It was mind-boggling! It makes so much more sense now, though! Thanks :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you say you don't have any "duplicate rows" - do any of the returned rows have the same Rep value? If so, the ordering within that will be indeterminate.

Try

```
orderby p.Rep descending, p.SubmitTime
```

(or some other ordering which will be completely determined) to get a more predictable result.

Also, is this LINQ to SQL? If so, you should look at the generated SQL to see what's happening.

Comment: That was exactly it. Including SubmitTime did the trick. Wow, I never would have guessed that was it, but now that I think about, it makes perfect sense why my original code didn't work. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I have been baffled by similar problems in paging when not using LINQ, but just using a SELECT query (in a sproc). I think that the issue may be that the Rep field is not unique, but the SubmitTime field, being a date, may be unique.

I would suggest that you try a second field after Rep to make the Order By always return the results in the same order. It can be any field that will make the records unique; you don't have to be using it in the results.

Answer (score 1):

The `Rep` column you are sorting by in the first case probably contains duplicates. When you select top 10 from a list containing 100 rows with value 1, there's no guarantee which rows will be returned. Change the order by clause to include a unique column.